# How to sort a dictionary of lists using a sorting algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, dictionary

Sorting dictionary of lists using a sorting algorithm in Python

I am  trying to sort (descending) a dictionary of lists without using canned functions and methods existing in Python (i.e. sorted() and .sort())

I created a function using bubble sort algorithm.
However it is sorting the elements but the keys are not being moved together with their corresponding elements.

Here is the function:

```
def bubbleDecDic(dictio):
    end=len(dictio)
    ndictio=dictio
    country=list(dictio.keys())
    for i in range(end-1,0,-1):
        for j in range(i):
            if ndictio[country[j]]< ndictio[country[j+1]]:
                ndictio[country[j+1]], ndictio[country[j]]= ndictio[country[j]], ndictio[country[j+1]]
    return ndictio
```

Here is an example of a input dictionary:

```
swim={'Russia': [0, 1, 1], 'China': [1, 2, 0], 'Australia': [1, 0, 0], 'Cuba': [1, 0, 0], 'Canada': [2, 1, 0]}

# input dictionary
# Country: [ gold, silver, bronze]
# gold > silver > bronze 

{'Russia': [0, 1, 1],
 'China': [1, 2, 0],
 'Australia': [1, 0, 0],
 'Cuba': [1, 0, 0],
 'Canada': [2, 1, 0]}


bubbleDecDic(swim)
```

The output keep the keys at the same position and sort the elements:

```
{'Russia': [2, 1, 0],
 'China': [1, 2, 0],
 'Australia': [1, 0, 0],
 'Cuba': [1, 0, 0],
 'Canada': [0, 1, 1]}
```

My goal is to sort by elements but the keys should go together.

This is the output I am trying to get:

```
{'Canada': [2, 1, 0],
 'China': [1, 2, 0],
 'Australia': [1, 0, 0],
 'Cuba': [1, 0, 0],
 'Russia': [0, 1, 1]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing is reassigning values to keys. You can sort the list of keys first and insert them along with values into an ordered dict.

```
key_list =sorted(d.keys()) # use any function to sort keys 
d= dict(zip(key_list, [d[i] for i in key_list ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries are ordered based on insertion order, so swapping dictionary entries like lists is probably not what you want. Instead I'd sort the keys and then create a new dictionary by associating those sorted keys with their original value.

```
def bubbleDecDic(dictio):
    end = len(dictio)
    countries = list(dictio)
    for i in range(end-1,0,-1):
        for j in range(i):
            if dictio[countries[j]] < dictio[countries[j + 1]]:
                countries[j + 1], countries[j] = countries[j], countries[j + 1]
    return {country: dictio[country] for country in countries}
```

(I didn't test it, but it's basically the same algorithm as the one you gave except that it changes the list of countries instead of `dictio`.)